# How do I declare (Dim) the sum of Application Matches in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to declare the sum of three *Application.Match* row numbers. If I add all these parts to *Watches* I see *Values* for each of my matches (e.g.: 1, 1, 1), but when I add them up I get "0" in the watch *Value*. Below is the related code and watch results when debugged.

```
Dim S13 As Integer
 S13 = Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0) + Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) + Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)
Dim SD13 As Integer
 SD13 = S13 / 3
```

**Watches:** Expression : Value : Type
Watch : Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0) : 1 : Variant/Double
Watch : Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) : 1 : Variant/Double
Watch : Application.Match(K(2), TF13, 0) : 1 : Variant/Double
Watch : **S13**    : 0 : Integer
Watch : SD13 : 0 : Integer

I tried "Long" and other declarations on S13, but I really only need it to be "Integer" because this number should exceed the type character limit.

**BTW**, I've tried to declare an easy formula like these below and still get "0" as a *Value* in the *Watches*.

```
Dim X As Integer: X = 3 / 3
Dim Y As Integer: Y = 1 + 1 + 1
Dim Z As Integer: Z = "1" + "1" + "1"
```

That said, I'm not so sure *Application.Match* has anything to do with the issue. Nonetheless, I figured I'd mention it for my case.

**UPDATE:** New Test Scenario
I opened up a new workbook and Module, entered the code below and got the expected result, "2" for TEST1 and "1" for TEST2. Looks like I may have a different issue affecting my other workbook. Anybody have an thoughts off the top of their head to help me start my investigation?

```
Sub TEST()
Dim TEST1 As Integer: TEST1 = 1 + 1 ' Works
Dim TEST2 As Integer: TEST2 = 2 / 2 ' Works
MsgBox TEST1 & " : " & TEST2 ' Message is "2 : 1"
End Sub
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
I figured out my issue, which could not be seen by the info provided (sorry). My code was like:

```
ElseIf...
'Dim don't go here...
    Dim S13 As Integer: S13 = Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)
    Dim SD13 As Integer: SD13 = S13 / 3
ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)) Then
    If <<some formula to help me validate match above (e.g.: all true and all same number)>> Then
      Worksheets("MATCHES").Range("$A" & ARR & ":" & "$F" & ARR) _
       = TR13.Range("$A" & SD13 & ":" & "$F" & SD13)
    End If
ElseIf...
```

That code placed my declarations before my *ElseIf/Then* (into the previous *ElseIf*) instead of placing it after the *Then* where the variables needed to be declared. Below is the correction.

```
ElseIf...
ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)) Then
'Dim go here...
    Dim S13 As Integer: S13 = Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)
    Dim SD13 As Integer: SD13 = S13 / 3
    If <<some formula to help me validate match above (e.g.: all true and all same number)>> Then
      Worksheets("MATCHES").Range("$A" & ARR & ":" & "$F" & ARR) _
       = TR13.Range("$A" & SD13 & ":" & "$F" & SD13)
    End If
ElseIf...
```

Comment: Try using ` \ ` instead of  ` / `, as you are returning it to an integer. Also, try CInt() around the Appilication.Match statements, as this is VBA Excel, not VB.Net
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator

Comment: @Cryostasys I wish I can say this is helpful, but I'm not clear on how/where exactly to apply your suggestions.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Using your code, `SD13` shows `1` in both the `Locals` and `Watch` windows.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that's strange. I can't even get the simple examples to work. Hmm.

Comment: FYI, I added an "UPDATE" test scenario yielding proper results.

Comment: @Cryostasys the integer division operator works in VBA as well... and `CInt` is redundant because if you're assigning to an `Integer`, the expression will silently be converted to `Integer`, *because* this is VBA and not VB.NET (.NET is much more strict with implicit conversions, especially with `Option Strict` on).

Comment: I appreciate the responds. I figured out my issue and posted as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim S13 As Integer
 S13 = CInt(Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0)) + CInt(Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0)) + CInt(Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0))
 Dim SD13 As Integer
  SD13 = S13 \ 3
```

Comment: This didn't work. I received the same results... Thanks for trying.

Comment: I actually just copied and pasted the code into a quick check on an open workbook I have, and it functioned. It may be some issue then with your variables; K(3), TF13, K(2), TC13, and K(1), TB13.

Comment: @DanielT are K(1), K(2), K(3), TF13, TC13, and TB13 variables in your Macro?
If you are trying to look in Cell TF13, you will need to use Range("TF13"), Rather than just putting it as TF13 - which is being treated as a Variable (An Array or Array Reference, to be specific).

Comment: I have a lot of variables and code around this, but I still can't get past why a simple TEST variable's declaration's value is "0" (e.g.: "Dim TEST As Integer: TEST = 1 + 1")

Comment: FYI, I added an "UPDATE" test scenario yielding proper results.

Comment: I can't tell you there. I can show you that it does work, but otherwise something is wrong with your system. [LINK](https://imgur.com/a/2leQjEO)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Cryostasys

Comment: Again, I just want you to know that I appreciate you responding. Also, I figured out my issue and posted as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
Dim S1 As Integer
Dim S2 As Integer
Dim S3 As Integer
S1 = Application.Match(K(3), Range("TF13"), 0) 
S2 = Application.Match(K(2), Range("TC13"), 0) 
S3 = Application.Match(K(1), Range("TB13"), 0)
Dim SD13 As Integer
SD13 = (S1 + S2 + S3) / 3

msgbox "S1: " & S1 & ", S2: " & S2 & ", S3: " & S3 & ", SD13: " & SD13
```

What the result S1, S2, S3 and SD13 now?

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but I figured out my issue and posted as my answer. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out my issue, which could not be seen by the info provided. Sorry.

My code was like this:

```
ElseIf...
'Dim don't go here...
    Dim S13 As Integer: S13 = Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)
    Dim SD13 As Integer: SD13 = S13 / 3
ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)) Then
    If <<some formula to help me validate match above (e.g.: all true and all same number)>> Then
      Worksheets("MATCHES").Range("$A" & ARR & ":" & "$F" & ARR) _
       = TR13.Range("$A" & SD13 & ":" & "$F" & SD13)
    End If
ElseIf...
```

This code placed my declarations before my *ElseIf/Then* (into the previous *ElseIf*) instead of placing it after the *Then* where the variables apparently needed to be declared. Below is the correction.

```
ElseIf...
ElseIf Not IsError(Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0)) _
  And Not IsError(Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)) Then
'Dim go here...
    Dim S13 As Integer: S13 = Application.Match(K(3), TF13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(2), TC13, 0) _
      + Application.Match(K(1), TB13, 0)
    Dim SD13 As Integer: SD13 = S13 / 3
    If <<some formula to help me validate match above (e.g.: all true and all same number)>> Then
      Worksheets("MATCHES").Range("$A" & ARR & ":" & "$F" & ARR) _
       = TR13.Range("$A" & SD13 & ":" & "$F" & SD13)
    End If
ElseIf...
```